# Как подсчитать кол-во букв, игнорируя HTML теги?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Высота дива высчитывается исходя из количество букв заголовка. При этом, нужно чтобы заголовок был в теге `<span>`, а высота должна указываться у дива.

Как мне посчитать кол-во букв внутри тега `<span>` и без пробелов?

```js
$('.textfill-departments').each(function() {
  var el = $(this);
  var textLength = el.html().length;
  if (textLength < 50) {
    el.css('height', '65px');
  } else if (textLength > 50) {
    el.css('height', '35px');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textfill-departments department-title">
  <span><?php print $title; ?></span>
</div>
```

Comment: посчитай в php и запиши в data-атрибут

Answer (score 3):

Берём первый вложенный элемент текущего элемента, получаем из него текст, разбиваем текст по пробелу, склеиваем текст без пробела:

```
var textLength= this.children[0].innerText.split(' ').join('').length;
```

Воспрооизводимый пример:

```js
    $('.textfill-departments').each(function(){
        let el = $(this);
        var textLength= this.children[0].innerText.split(' ').join('').length; 
        if (textLength < 50) {
        console.log('меньше 50');
            el.css('height', '65px');
        }
        else if (textLength > 50) {
        console.log('больше 50');
            el.css('height', '35px');
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textfill-departments department-title">


    <span><?php print $title; ?></span>


</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте класс заголовку. И если там может содержатся внутри разметка, то
вместо `html()` используйте `text()`

```js
$('.textfill-departments').each(function(){
     let len = $(this).children(".title").text().replace(/\s/g, '').length;     
     let w = len > 50 ? '35px' : '65px';
     $(this).css('height', w);              
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textfill-departments">123 <span class="title">qwe</span></div>
```